# Verifying the Measurement Precision of a Circuit

Tags: analog, voltage-measurement, pulse, integrator, precision

My aim is to build an electronic circuit that allows me to measure the relative precision of the energy of optical pulses in the order of 10^-6. The optical power of the laser pulses is measured with a photodetector that gives an output in Volts, proportional to the laser power.

For measuring the relative precision of my optical pulse energy, I will build an analog circuit with an integrator and a sample and hold part. This will integrate the voltage signal from the photodetector and holds the value of the integration for read-out with a digitizer. The final read-out value is proportional to the optical pulse energy and I'm interested in the relative precision of repeated pulses.

How can I verify that my electronic circuit allows me to measure with a relative precision of 10^-6?

Comment: what's "area of a pulse"? is 10⁻⁶ a relative precision, or is it missing a unit?

Comment: Yes, 10^-6 is a relative precision. The area of the pulse is the energy of the pulse or the integrated power/voltage over time.

Comment: Could you then please write "energy"? That's not the same as integrated voltage, but it is integrated power, so you see how the term "area" is ambiguous.

Comment: nevertheless, what's the unit of the signal you're observing? Is it voltage or current, or power?

Comment: Ok, we have a voltage signal! But you want energy through integration of power. So, we will have to find the relationship between voltage and power. Do you have a constant-impedance load attached over which you measure that voltage?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I updated the question and hope it is clear now. The voltage signal of the photodetector is proportional to the optical power of the pulse. I thus do not worry about the conversion. The input of my circuit is a voltage pulse. I integrate the pulse and hold the value at the end of the pulse for readout. For a series of evaluated pulses, I am interested in their relative precision. How can I verify that my circuit can perform at such a precision?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that's much clearer.